# Querydsl - How use group by and sum

Tags: group-by, sum, querydsl

I'd like to do a query than in sql it's:

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(total), SUM(total*price) FROM sales INNER JOIN users ON sales.id_user=users.id GROUP BY users.id
```

I tried searching for the solution, but the closest I get was:

```
QSales sales = QSales.sales;
JPAQuery query = from(sales);
QUsers users = QUsers.users;
query.innerJoin(sales.users, users);
List<Object[]> response = query.groupBy(sales.user).list(sales.user, sales.total.sum());
```

but i don't know how to get this:

```
SUM(total*price)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUM(total*price)
```

can be expressed as

```
total.multiply(price).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NumberExpression

```
NumberExpression totalPrice = sales.total.multiply(sales.price);
```

then use totalPrice.sum()